# Multiple Filters of Pivot Table

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a pivot table with 2 filters: Main LOB and Sub LOB. Whenever I am choosing a Main LOB from its filter, all the available Sub LOBs are also showing instead of just the Sub LOBs of the selected Main LOB. How do I show just the Sub LOBs of the selected Main LOB?

Here's what I have so far:

```
With PT
If pf1.CurrentPage.Name = CurrentCat Then
  For Each pit In pf2.PivotItems
      With Destn1
        .Value = pit.Name & " Agents "
        With .Font
          .Name = "Calibri"
          .Size = 11
          .Underline = xlUnderlineStyleSingle
          .Bold = True
        End With
      End With
      Set Destn1 = Destn1.Offset(2)
      pf2.ClearAllFilters    'added this line (makes it a bit more robust).
      pf2.CurrentPage = pit.Name
      With .TableRange1
        .Copy
        Destn1.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
        Set myTable = NewSht.ListObjects.Add(xlSrcRange, Destn1.Resize(.Rows.Count, .Columns.Count), , xlYes)
        myTable.TableStyle = "TableStyleMedium14"
        myTable.ShowTableStyleRowStripes = False
        Set Destn1 = Destn1.Offset(.Rows.Count + 2)
      End With    '.TableRange1
      myTable.Unlist
    Next pit
  End If
'End If
End With    'PT
```

Comment: Have you considered using Slicers rather than old-style filters? They are ideal for this purpose - you can configure the Sub-LOB slicer to actually hide the options which make no sense based on the primary LOB (the default is just to change their appearance to show them as unavailable and move them to the end of the list).

Comment: not yet.. I have other pivot tables that use the filters and I was wanting to keep it that way if possible

Comment: That would be another reason to use slicers - you can configure a slicer to filter multiple PTs at the same time (or not, it's up to you). If you also add a filter to the PT for the same field/attribute then you will see the selected item in the filter just as if you had selected it there. This might be useful for other reasons such as printing, or so you can reference the filtered value (since it is in a cell), such as in a report title: "Report of <things> sold in <region> during <period>"